# Sharepoint master page asp:repeater tag

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am currently working on generating a master page for a sharepoint instance. It is however giving some issues when attempting to convert over an ASP repeater

The following works in generating a repeated text:

```
    <!--MS:<asp:Repeater ID="TopMenu" runat="server" DataSourceID="selectedSiteMap">-->
    <!--MS:<HeaderTemplate> -->

    <!--ME:</HeaderTemplate> -->
    <!--MS:<ItemTemplate> -->
        <li><a href="" class="link">test</a></li>
    <!--ME:</ItemTemplate> -->
    <!--MS:<FooterTemplate> -->

    <!--ME:</FooterTemplate> -->
<!--ME:</asp:Repeater> -->
<!--MS:<asp:SiteMapDataSource SiteMapProvider="CurrentNavigation" ShowStartingNode="false"
    StartFromCurrentNode="false" StartingNodeOffset="0" StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002"
    EnableViewState="true" ID="selectedSiteMap" runat="server" /> -->
```

However the following does not work:

```
    <!--MS:<asp:Repeater ID="TopMenu" runat="server" DataSourceID="selectedSiteMap">-->
    <!--MS:<HeaderTemplate> -->
        <ul id="main_menu_ul" class="">
    <!--ME:</HeaderTemplate> -->
    <!--MS:<ItemTemplate> -->
        <li><a href=<!--MS:"<%# Eval("Url")%>"--> class="link">
            <!--MS:<%# Eval("Title")%>--></a></li>
    <!--ME:</ItemTemplate> -->
    <!--MS:<FooterTemplate> -->
        </ul>
    <!--ME:</FooterTemplate> -->
<!--ME:</asp:Repeater> -->
<!--MS:<asp:SiteMapDataSource SiteMapProvider="CurrentNavigation" ShowStartingNode="false"
    StartFromCurrentNode="false" StartingNodeOffset="0" StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002"
    EnableViewState="true" ID="selectedSiteMap" runat="server" /> -->
```

So far I have identified the issue is 2 fold: 
1. the converter is does not like the fact that the opening ul and closing ul dont exactly match
2. the converter does not like the eval tags at all.

Any help anyone could give to getting this repeater to work properly would be very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other possibility is that you are manually uploading your master page (as opposed to deploying it using a feature). The <%# Eval("Url")%> tag is seen as server-side code, and it turns out that there is a security limitation that server-side code is not allowed in customized pages - in other words, ones that are unghosted.

So if you customize a master page using SharePoint designer, the new copy exists in the content database, and this is regarded as customized.

I hit this recently - deployed an aspx master page (with a repeater control in it) using a feature, download a copy, re-upload it (with no changes) and bang - error. Code blocks not allowed in this file.

As you're putting this in an html master page, you're probably just masking the real reason for the error. You could try adding an entry to the web.config (see, for example, [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2007/04/26/code-blocks-are-not-allowed-in-this-file-using-server-side-code-with-sharepoint.aspx)) to specify that your master page can have code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

It might because You have opened
MS: before you Eval("") but there is no closing ME: after eval tag.

Comment: As I said I've tried removing the evals separate from the rest to no effect.